# How to update child component when parent updated in react?

Tags: reactjs

In react-router app I have this root component:

```
<div className="page">
    { this.props.children || <Home /> }
    <Footer/>
</div>
```

On some event state changed and this calls render method. First rendered root component, then footer, but home or other components not rerendered. Is there the way to fix it?

Comment: What happens on first render? Do you then see home or children?

Comment: @wintvelt, it's depends. If app opened on home page - Home, else - Child component.

Comment: So it works on first render, but is broken on re-render?

Comment: @wintvelt, yes, it works on first render, but it isn't broken on re-render.  

`App` component is wrapper for `Home` and `Child` components, and I would like to `Home` or `Child` re-render, when I call `this.setState({state: newState})` in `App`. But render method calls only in `App` and `Footer`.

Comment: I think I understand: `this.setState()` does NOT re-render `<Home>` or `this.props.children`. The code you shared is fine. My guess: somewhere else in your code you modify `this.props.children`, which then becomes an empty object. The empty object is then rendered, but does not show anything. You would need to share other code to get help on this.

Comment: @wintvelt, little different: render method not call and object in `this.props.children` is visible. Full code [here](https://gist.github.com/xuraganx/cd9df4aa738df55ea15c). When I load page first in console show:
`App component, Home component, Footer component` and when state updated: only `App component,  Footer component`